# How to change the position of an UITableView in a View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a view where I push a button and this code is loaded:

```
    TestView *testView = [[TestView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:nil];        
    [testView.table setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 188)];        

    testView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [(UIViewController*) currentOb presentModalViewController:testview animated:YES];
```

The nib of TestView, where I have a table, is loaded fine, but the table is still in the position (0,0) intead of (0,200). Do u know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks and sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
testview.table.frame = CGRectMake(0,200,320,188);
```

Comment: you can create a property (with an IBOutlet) for your table view and modify that directly.

Comment: Yes, I do that in my TestView class:

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;

But I need to modify its position according diferent cases. So I have to change the position by code.

Comment: you should be able to access the table directly without having to go through the testview.      something like      self.table.frame = CGRect(.....

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect the table outlet of TestView to the table in Interface Builder? It's easy to forget, in which case something like this would happen.

Comment: Is the code sample correct? Your presentModalViewController call uses testview (all lowercase) but all the other code shown use testView (uppercase V). So either your code sample is incorrect or you have two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

i find this, it can be the best solution for this problem:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50,0,0,0)];
```